# Getting single unified instance of recurring events and non recurring events

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get one *unified* instance of a recurring event and the changes I make in that to reflect in all instances of that recurring event.

`calendar.getEvents` returns a single instance for a each event in a recurring series. i.e if I do any changes to that instance, like deleting it, only that particular instance gets deleted. I tried using `getEventSeries()` and `deleteEventSeries()` but these do not reflect in the array, so I ended up calling `getEvents` every time I delete. Is this the best way to do it? or is there an alternative available?

```js
//The object of the following code is to delete all events in a calendar
function delete_events(calendar) {
  var fromDate = new Date("January 1, 1900 00:00:00");
  var toDate = new Date("January 1, 2100 00:00:00");
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);

  while (events.length > 0) {
    var ev = events[0];
    var es = ev.getEventSeries();
    es.deleteEventSeries();
    Logger.log('Deleted: ' + es.getTitle());

    events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wrote a script to solve that kind of issues, see this page:   https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/calendar/calendar_edit_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since eventsSeries have the same ID you can simplify the process by simply remembering these IDs and skip these events on the following iterations.

Here is a simple test code :

```
function test(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('some calendar name you own')[0];
  delete_events(cal);
}

function delete_events(cal) {
  var fromDate = new Date("January 1, 2014 00:00:00");
  var toDate = new Date("January 1, 2100 00:00:00");
  var events = cal.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
  var IDs = [];
  for(var n in events){
    Logger.log(events[n].getTitle());
    var id = events[n].getId();
    if(IDs.indexOf(id)>-1){continue};
    try{
      cal.getEventSeriesById(id).deleteEventSeries();
      IDs.push(id);
      Logger.log(events[n].getTitle()+' was deleted,  ID = '+events[n].getId());
    }catch(err){Logger.log(events[n].getTitle()+' on '+Utilities.formatDate(events[n].getStartTime(),cal.getTimeZone(),'yyyy/MMM/dd')+" was not deleted,you don't have the right to modify it");}
  }
}
```